# Unable to create a Windows Core VM instance using gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I wanted to create a Windows VM using gcloud command line.

Tried the "Equivalent Command Line" syntax - the syntax failed.

After some trial and error, discovered that the --create-disk list of parameters needs to be repeated (please observe the script below).

```
gcloud compute instances create ifworker-0 \
--project=ceng-test \
--zone=us-east4-c \
--machine-type=n2-standard-2 \
--network-interface=nic-type=VIRTIO_NET \
--network-tier=PREMIUM \
--maintenance-policy=MIGRATE \
--provisioning-model=STANDARD \
--service-account=the-service-account \
--scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform \
--tags=ifworker-net-0 \
--create-disk=mode=rw \
--create-disk=size=40GB \
--create-disk=type=projects/ceng-test/zones/us-central1-a/diskTypes/pd-balanced \
--create-disk=boot=yes \
--create-disk=auto-delete=yes \
--create-disk=image=projects/windows-cloud/global/images/windows-server-2022-dc-core-v20220513 \
--no-shielded-secure-boot \
--shielded-vtpm \
--shielded-integrity-monitoring \
--reservation-affinity=any
```

However, even then the script is failing - the error is reproduced below.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
- Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[0]': '{
  "type": "PERSISTENT",  
  "mode": "READ_WRITE",  
  "boot": true,  
  "initializeParams": {  },  
  "autoDele...'. 
Boot disk must have a source specified.
```

Need some guidance here. Thanks for your attention and time.

Answer (score 1):

As checked on your command, `boot` and `image` properties should be in the same line.

It should look like this.

```
--create-disk=boot=yes,image=projects/windows-cloud/global/images/windows-server-2022-dc-core-v20220513
```

Based on GCP's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create#--create-disk) the `image` properties should be included in the same line with `--create-disk=[PROPERTY=VALUE,…]` parameters, specifying the name of the image that will be initialized.

Below is the command that worked on my end:

```
gcloud compute instances create ifworker-0 \
--project=<project_name> \
--zone=us-east4-c \
--machine-type=n2-standard-2 \
--network-interface=nic-type=VIRTIO_NET \
--network-tier=PREMIUM \
--maintenance-policy=MIGRATE \
--provisioning-model=STANDARD \
--service-account=the-service-account \
--scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform \
--tags=ifworker-net-0 \
--create-disk=mode=rw \
--create-disk=size=40GB \
--create-disk=type=projects/ceng-test/zones/us-central1-a/diskTypes/pd-balanced \
--create-disk=boot=yes,image=projects/windows-cloud/global/images/windows-server-2022-dc-core-v20220513 \
--create-disk=auto-delete=yes \
--no-shielded-secure-boot \
--shielded-vtpm \
--shielded-integrity-monitoring \
--reservation-affinity=any
```

Note:
Change *<project_name>* and/or *service account* details.

Comment: Regrets but that does not work ... the response is ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) argument --create-disk: Invalid flag value [yes image=projects/windows-cloud/global/images/windows-server-2022-dc-core-v20220513], expected one of [true, yes, false, no] - basically combining the two on a same line is creating an error where the system thinks both the items are components of the response.

Comment: @quasar66 can you update your question and post the updated commands that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

For "gcloud compute instances create" there should be only one --create-disk line per disk. In other cases multiple disks are created.
As we want only one disk, there should be only one line, with all parameters delimited by ",".

The correct example follows.

```
gcloud compute instances create ifworker-0 \
--project=<project_name> \
--zone=us-east4-c \
--machine-type=e2-micro \
--network-interface=nic-type=VIRTIO_NET \
--network-tier=PREMIUM \
--maintenance-policy=MIGRATE \
--provisioning-model=STANDARD \
--scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform \
--tags=ifworker-net-0 \
--create-disk=mode=rw,size=40GB,type=projects/<project_name>/zones/us-central1-a/diskTypes/pd-balanced,boot=yes,auto-delete=yes,image=projects/windows-cloud/global/images/windows-server-2022-dc-core-v20220513  \
--no-shielded-secure-boot \
--shielded-vtpm \
--shielded-integrity-monitoring \
--reservation-affinity=any
```